# gemspec dependencies definition and require conflict

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemspecs

I have a conflict between the **gem dependencies definitions** and the **require** of these gems.

I have this:

```
# Gemfile
source "http://rubygems.org"
gemspec
```

-

```
# my_gem.gemspec
$:.push File.expand_path("../lib", __FILE__)
require "my_gem"

Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.version = MyGem::VERSION
  # ...
  s.add_dependency "s3"
end
```

-

```
# /lib/my_gem.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 's3'
```

The conflict line is the *s3 requirement* because when I execute `bundle install` it complains because this gem is not installed yet.

The workaround is to comment this require, then execute `bundle install` and uncomment the require again what is not pretty at all.

Any suggestion is welcome, if you need more details to understand the problem please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't require your entire gem in your gemspec. Move your version info to a path like "lib/my_gem/version.rb" and require that. Secondly, you shouldn't do a "require 'rubygems'" unless you're using the Rubygems API for some feature. There are some users that don't use Rubygems, and you shouldn't force them to use it unless necessary.

Comment: working as a charm, thanks.. and also thanks for the **not require rubygems** tip, I have been reading about this, I have changed my _require_ by this other: https://gist.github.com/1105149

Comment: As your library is gona be run with rubygems, there is no need to require rubygems at all.

When testing, for examples binaries, use ruby -I lib -rubygems bin/mybinnary

Comment: rubygems is built in to ruby 1.9.3 so it's a non-issue from there on.

Answer (score 1):

1.- Do not require 'rubygems' in a library. Is like if a unix program requires apt-get, so no other system can't use your library.

2.- In the library, put your version in a separate file /lib/lib_name/version.rb and require that file on gemspec. Only that file, so you don't load your library and dependecies when trying to loading the gemspec.